# Why is Permission table populated in test database, while others aren't (django python)?

Tags: python, django, testing

While playing around with django testing I noticed that `Permission` table in test database is not empty (like, for example, `User` and tables of models defined by me) - it has all permissions from the real table.
[image: pdb]

My questions:

1. Is the `Permission` table the only prepopulated table? (I have trouble inspecting other tables, because db is in-memory)
2. Where is it prepopulated (I also couldn't find)? Upon setting up test suit? Or just before executing each test method? Or maybe added to queryset everytime it is requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are created when you run [`manage.py migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/), there is a signal handler that listens to the [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_migrate) signal and creates these permissions for every new model.

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)

The [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) table will also be populated in a similar manner

When you run your tests, your test DB will have your migrations applied to it